# PHP IDE for Search in remote file without store the files to local

Tags: php, search, ide

Are there any good IDEs which can search for a word or phrase from the remote files without storing/synchroning to my local computer first?

I have tried Aptana, but it doesn't seem to be able to do this but, the remote file system is good(not store to local)

I have tried Netbeans, which seems to alway store files to my local machine first.

I hoping that there are (preferably free) IDEs out there that can run searches for strings on the my remote host?

Comment: This is an interesting question, and for those who have voted to close this, please keep in mind that questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers" are explicitly included as on-topic. The OP is not asking for a laundry-list of products with some vague "What's IDE is best?" question. He asked if there is any IDE that can perform a very specific (and useful) task.

Comment: @BenD feel free to extend my list... :)

Comment: @hek2mgl - I wish I could. Whenever I need to do this I always synchronize (if it's a small site) or `grep` from Linux command line

Comment: @BenD 'Always synchronize' using FTP? (would do too, if someone forces me to use IDE instead of vim ;)  'grep from the Linux command line' .. can you explain this?

Comment: If you're searching for a specific string within a project [`grep`](http://www.linfo.org/grep.html) lets you search for patterns in specific files, file-types, directories, etc. So if I want to find files with specific content without downloading a project back to my local machine, it's a quick and pretty powerful, but it has to be done outside an IDE to my knowledge.

Comment: Can you outline why you want to search your remote files? In general, your local files will be a mirror of your remote server, so you can just search the local files? Do you have a remote cache or something that doesn't exist locally?

Comment: Forgive me, i think it's something like 'temporary' storing and not storing all the files. I add a comment in the answer's question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see three possible (common) options:

- Connect via ssh and use [`vim`](http://www.vim.org/). I would do that.
- Mount the remote file system via scp (sshfs on Linux) or ftp (curlftpfs on Linux). This will hide file transmission from you but they **will** be done it background. So it's much the same as let the IDE do the ftp work
- Have the IDE (whatever you prefer) running on the remote host and using RemoteDesktop or somewhat else.

I prefer ssh + vim :)

---

Using ssh may be the most secure and usual approach. The less data intensive will be using FTP with Aptana as you already doing (Expecting that Aptana just transmitts changed files). (Also this may depend on the filesize and circumstances but with usual code files I would say so)

---

If you are working on Windows [expandrive](http://www.expandrive.com/) might be an approach. It supports mounting remote servers a local netdrive in Windows via FTP, SSH or SFTP . An IDE would see that folder like a local folder. You should give it a try.

---

Update: Trying to explain more....

If you want to search in a remote file, you have two general options:

- The search program runs locally and will need input data from remote (the file)
- The serach program runs remotely. You'll send arguments to it, and it will send back the search results

No further options.

In IDE speaks it means: Either you use the search functionality of your IDE itself, means the search program (IDE) runs locally, then the file has to be downloaded / sychnronized / netmounted whatever. Or you execute grep or whatever remotely and display the results. Then it mostly comes to ssh. Your IDE will need a ssh plugin for that. Eclipse for example has one. (Think to remember the name was RSE. [Remote Systems Explorer](http://www.eclipse.org/tm/)) (It will work with Aptana too) .

Comment: newbie question:can we mount the remote file system in windows? i have no Linux OS installed right now.

Comment: Hehe :) things that can be done in a second on linux are sometimes hard on Windows ... Question: Is the remote machine also a Windows box?

Comment: Is 'remote machine' mean server? my site's server use Linux.

Comment: Try this : http://www.expandrive.com/ I've once used it for the same purpose. It supports FTP, SCP, SFTP. You can mount your server as netdrive and Aptana will see it like a local working folder.

Comment: There is a 'Manage SSH Keys' in my cpanel (i use shared hosting right now), i just don't know how to use it or take the benefit with it.

Comment: Yes, cpanel supports ssh and so you should use it as it is most secure. (ftp is plaintext, means 0% secure). But thats a topic for another question ;) First you can try the software I suggested above. It also supports FTP. If you once start to use ssh it will work too

Comment: Wow, the software looked like what i wanted! Thankyou! I think i'll give a try for your suggestions when i'm ready on Linux :)

Comment: According to my question, i looking for an IDE. Sorry for unmark.

Comment: You can use Aptana (as you already mentioned) or any other IDE available. The netdrive is just like a virtual hard drive. You create just a local project but files are saved remotely - behind the scenes. The IDE will not even know about this fact. You may have to configure a path mapping like 'Z:\\myproject\' -> 'http://mysite.com/myproject/' (depends on IDE). I've worked a couple of years this way

Comment: Yes, Sir. I just want to make the question on the topic. My real problem is solved, but the question's problem has not been solved yet.(PHP IDE which has Search ability in remote files without storing the files)

Comment: Thats because of the nature of networking and computing. How should this *magic* IDE work? The simple answer to the question is: There is no IDE for that

Comment: @Azhar - hek2mgl is entirely right. Setting up a virtual filing system that "contains" the files on the remote server does not, in general, store anything locally. All file operations are converted to equivalent operations on the remote server, and are performed using a networking protocol native to the remote server.

Comment: @hek2mgl and halfer, forgive me, i think it's like do a 'temporary' storing. However, i found Microsoft Expression Web 4(It has a free version) can do this 'temporary' storing and actually nearly what i want(Not store locally all files, only if the file needed). Now, i found the IDE, so this question not 'off the topic'. And, Thankyou very much for the explanation Sir! i learn a lot today :)