# Alternative FTP client for Windows

Tags: php, windows, ftp, webserver

I am looking for an alternative FTP client for a windows machine. I am currently using fileZila. 
I am looking for something that:

- Has better file interface
- Can edit and change files easier

I am basically looking for something that can allow me to edit my ftp files on a folder on windows,
on a concept really similar to SVN (But without requiring to submit files and go through so much to update your copy).

Comment: I don't think this question belongs here, should be moved to superuser

Comment: Sorry, new to StackOverflow, how to do that?

Comment: If you're only accessing a single or few ftp servers, then you could map them on your harddrive.

Comment: Yeah I would love to map it on my harddrive, can you please post how?

Comment: http://superuser.com/

Comment: @Danny - I don't think you can do this by yourself. The question might need to be closed first and then migrated. So for now just leave it as it is and if need it will be moved.

Comment: There are a lot of programs, webdrive ( http://www.webdrive.com/products/webdrive/index.html ) for instance, a simple google search will find you more :) and likely something free too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally an IDE like Eclipse, Aptana, PHP storm, ... should already contain an integrated FTP client. Have you tried them? Mostly they support a feature like *upload to server on file save* . This should fit your needs

If you are looking for a solution beside from an IDE you can try [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/). I've used it over years. It supports SFTP, SCP and plain FTP as well. The built in editor isn't sufficient but you can configure your own editor for each file type. Let's say notepad++ for php files and photoshop for jpegs.

---

Update: You can also map the FTP folder to a windows drive. [Expandrive](http://www.expandrive.com/) should be what you are looking for if you work with Windows.

Comment: Mapping it to a drive helps better. However, thanks for your help!

Comment: Also this answer to a related question may be helpful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15104385/171318

Comment: Yeah that sounds really good. Thanks a lot!