# How to make Notepad++ run the PHP file on the server that I set?

Tags: notepad++, server-side, filezilla

It is my first time touching on php and I'm learning the basics of it. I've used Notepad++ for all of my HTML, CSS, and javascript files. Since, theses three are able to test and run locally, php isnt because it's a server side which requires a server to run. I was wondering, if there's a way to make Notepad++ run the file on the server?

In the Notepadd++ title header, it gives the local directory "C:\Users\Jaime\Desktop\grade.php" of my file, but can this directory be altered to something like "http://" indicating it's being tested and run on the internet?

If not, is there anything else I can use to efficiently run php files without having to refresh and put the files in Filezilla to see the changes made?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to run .php files on my local computer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318858/is-it-possible-to-run-php-files-on-my-local-computer)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP IDE for Search in remote file without store the files to local](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15104132)

Comment: @mario those 2 are not related! TheAmazingKnight I would advise you to remove any references to PHP because it is irrelevant and confused people. Your question is about **Notepad++ being able or not to execute a script (PHP, Python, Perl, whatever) that's not stored locally**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you probably need is an [FTP Synchronize plugin](http://www.rarst.net/software/notepadpp-ftp-plugin/) that will allow you to edit a copy of your php file and then synchronize it to the server.

**How to Install:**

1. Make sure that your Notepad++ is closed
2. Download from this [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/FTP_synchronize/) . I choose version 0.9.6.1. Unpack or Unzip to \Notepad++\plugin folder.
3. It will have its own folder so copy or cut and paste the files to
   \Notepad++\plugin
4. Read the file named "What file to use" so that you will know which
   to use. In my case I used `FTP_synchronize.dll`
5. Run your Notepad++ and it will tell you that it will remove the
   unwanted files and just click Ok for it.
6. Go to Plugin-->FTP Synchronize-->Show FTP Folders. And presto there
   you have it!

**How to Connect:**

*Go to menu Plugins-->FTP Synchronize-->Show FTP Folders*

[image: Go to Menu Plugin]

*Click Open Settings Dialog*

[image]

*Click the New Button then type-in the Address, Port, Username,
    Password and check Active on Connection Mode. And finally Click OK.*

[image]

*Click Connect*

[image]

*Click upload Current File to Folder*

[image]

Then check your website and in my case the files uploaded are on the login name that I used that turned into a folder. And inside the folder are the files that I uploaded. Or of course you could really go directly to the `wwwroot` folder (or whatever folder name for your root) if you like so that you don't have to transfer the files.

Comment: How do I use it because the link you provided isn't clear enough on how to install and begin using it right away.

Answer (score 6):

These answers so far deal with either running PHP locally or synchronizing with a server (which it seems like you were already doing), but none seem to address actually executing the PHP script from Notepad++, which I think was your main question. I'm not an expert on Notepad++ by any means, but here's what I came up with:

1. Go to Run -> Run...
2. Type in `firefox "http://yourserver.com/$(FILE_NAME)"`
3. Hit "Save..."
4. Type in a name like "Run on Server"
5. Pick a keyboard shortcut
6. Hit OK, then Cancel

Replace "yourserver.com" with the URL to your web server. This shortcut should launch Firefox and point it at http://yourserver.com/YourCurrentFile.php, assuming the file you were editing was something like `C:\Users\TheAmazingKnight\Desktop\PHP\YourCurrentFile.php`. It's not a perfect solution, but you should be able to tweak it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [WAMP Server](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) - it's easy to install and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

You could install the XAMPP server in your machine.

The server will run in a directory you choose, and you will be able to run PHP files from your browser in the `http://localhost` address.

You find XAMPP here: http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html

Comment: I have no idea how to use XAMPP. I downloaded it but have no idea where to begin. How do I set it up and make changes on the server with the files on there using XAMPP?

Comment: It is easy to use. You can find more information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652491/how-to-use-xampp-with-php) and [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/shorttutorials/run-a-php-program-in-xampp-server).  You can also search for more tutorials.

Comment: Thanks Diego! I'm a step closer to making it work. When I run Apache and put in http://localhost in the firefox browser, it just shows a blank page, nothing is being displayed like it should show XAMPP's website. I tried the same with Filezilla, same results, any idea why this occurred?

Comment: When you configure the XAMPP correctly, `http://localhost` should point to your htdocs XAMPP directory. In this directory you can find a index.html, that is the page that should be displayed. You can put other files in this directory (usually C:\xampp\htdocs) and point to them in the browser. Example `http://localhost/newpage.html`.